# Image PPI and dimensions

Tags: image, image-processing, png, jpeg

Let's say I have an original PNG image 60x60 at 144 PPI (Pixels Per Inch).  I need to have two images at 60x60 (72 DPI) and 120x120 (72 DPI) dimensions.

Since the original image has a 144 PPI, can I make it to 120x120 without seeing any degrading the image quality.  Will the result have the same as making the image at 120x120 at 72 PPI beginning with?

Comment: As long as you don't output your image to paper, the PPI/DPI and what ever has no meaning. Its only about pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPI relates image size in pixels to image size in inches (or whatever physical distance unit).

Hence, when a 60x60 image  at 144 PPI has a physical size of 0.42x0.42 inches.
When you say that you need to have an image at 60x60 and 72 DPI -that would imply a physical size of 0.83x0.83 inches- you don't make clear if you want to respect the original physical dimensions (in that case, you could pad the original image with a blank margin, and resample it to 60 pixels), or not (in that case, you'd simply change do a physical scale of the image, which would amount to changing the PPI, and no need of pixels resampling).

Once you define what you want, the rest of the question, I think, is easy to answer.

Comment: So if I have an 60x60 pixels image, regardless of the PPI or DPI I won't be able to make a 120x120 without diminishing the quality of the 120x120 image? ( view on the tablet screen)

Comment: That's right, if you have a tiny image you can resample it to a higher pixel size, but you won't be able to get a high quality image.